# Visual studio can't detect latest typescript version

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have just updated my Typescript version through npm to V3.2.2 after I discovered that VS is using 2.6 and I need something from V2.9 at least.

I verified this with the `tsc --version` command, which gives me "Version 3.2.2" as output.

Now, however, when I want to update the Version for my project through the project properties in VS2017, I am still only able to use the old 2.6 version.

I tried this through the following guide: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017

With this help, I went to the csproj and manually updated the version number to the desired one. After restarting VS, I get a message stating that the (now) V3.2.2 is unavailable, and whether I want to downgrade to 2.6 again.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using VS2017, V15.6.1